# Subtraction and Addition in one Mysql statement

Tags: mysql

I have a number of tables I'm looking to manipulate. I want to get the total of all balances a user has, from this I wish to subtract the total of all their credit card balances plus the total of all bills that still need to be paid until the end of the month.
I have a very busy Mysql query but it keeps getting rejected.
Various parts of it work individually but I cannot get the complete query to work.

```
   Select Sum ((Select SUM(Balance) from account)-
(Select sum((select sum(Balance) from credit_card) - (select sum(Amount) FROM bills where Date > 12)))
```

Can anyone see where I have gone wrong?

Comment: You don't have multiple users? This is a query for all users. You might be able to get a much simpler query if you share your tables structure and some sample data.

Comment: Along with what Filipe said, can you explain what you mean by your query getting "rejected?"  Is MySQL displaying an error when you try to run your query, or do you have a DBA that won't let you run it as it's currently written?

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:

1) Check your parenthesis. It look s like you are missing the outermost one.
2) In the second select clause where you subtract sum(balance) from sum(amount), there is no real need need for a separate select and SUM clause.

Given a query, if you are including GROUP BY column, then make the outermost SELECT to make use of SUM

```
SELECT ( (SELECT SUM (Balance) FROM account)
            - ((SELECT sum (Balance) FROM credit_card)
                           - (SELECT sum (Amount)
                                FROM bills
                               WHERE Date > 12))
```

Comment: There will only be a single user. The Accounts table contains there various bank accounts, ie account name, bank name, account balance. So if the have two bank accounts it will have two balances. The credit card table will have the same set up. Finally the bills table has details of monthly outgoings, provider name , amount (ie Sky, 40.00) The thought for the query is that a user will know at any point in the month their financial position, even taking into account the amount still to come out for regular bills that month.

Comment: If it's for a single user, no GROUP BY is required

Comment: The error I get is #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1. I dont have any quote marks on line 1 though.